# Is it ever faster to slide instead of sprint when travelling over flat terrain?

Tags: apex-legends

In Apex Legends, while you're sprinting you can use the crouch ability to slide forward until friction drags you to a stop. This is mainly useful when you're sliding down a hill, or attempting to be evasive.

[image: "Sliding down hills increases speed."]

Even on flat ground it *looks* like you might gain speed for a moment when you start to slide. It seems like you might be able to maintain an average speed faster than sprinting alone by repeatedly sliding and sprinting. However, I'm not sure if this is actually faster, or if it's just the camera movement playing tricks on me.

Is it ever faster to mix in slides when you're sprinting over flat terrain in Apex Legends, or is sprinting always the faster choice?

Comment: I havent tested it actually, but as the game seems to be a spin-off of Titanfall, I'd assume, that sliding is indeed faster

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**, you can move faster by mixing in slides than by just sprinting.

I tried both in the training room and recorded the results:

Comment: Perfect simple video demonstration +1

Comment: Make sure to remember about slide cooldown(`2 seconds`). If you attempt to slide before the cooldown, you will get deadslides.

Answer (score 9):

Sliding is indeed faster, even on a level surface.

I have tested this several times now alongside teammates who are only sprinting.

Also, if you jump at the end of your slide you can carry that slightly faster speed for a bit in the air as well. I've even found that up a slight incline you can still get a little speed boost if you slide and jump right away.